# Bing api APPID, for win 8 app

Tags: windows, azure, bing, bing-api

I'm developing a Win 8 App that needs to interact with Bing Api, but it needs an APPID, looking at windows azure find that it provides APPID's for azure market place.

All that i need is for win8 app.

Where can i find or get an app id for a Win8 APP that works with bing api?

Comment: Did you ever find out the answer to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sign up https://datamarket.azure.com/ which will give you a primary account key.  Account keys are then used to access the Windows Azure Marketplace dataset subscriptions.

To subscribe, click on "Data" and then the service you want.  Sign up for whatever level of service you want.

Comment: Tks @Graham Chiu. finally end my Project using a WEB control that points to Bings page. But your soulution looks mor professional. I'm going to try it.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but see http://www.bendemeyer.com/2013/04/02/bing-spelling-suggestions-and-wordpress-search/ The POST uses basic authentication to access the web service where the user is blank (I think), and the password is your account key.  So, you need to setup your http headers appropriately